# Memory pressure issue while downloading multiple files using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, memory-pressure

In my application i am trying to download thousands of images (each image size with a maximum of 3mb) and 10's of videos (each video size with a maximum of 100mb) and saving it in Documents Directory.

To achieve this i am using AFNetworking

Here my problem is i am getting all the data **successfully when i am using a slow wifi (around 4mbps)**, but the same downloading if i am doing under a ***wifi with a speed of 100mbps*** the application is getting **memory warning while downloading images and memory pressure issue while downloading videos and then application is crashing**.

```
-(void) AddVideoIntoDocument :(NSString *)name :(NSString *)urlAddress{

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:1000.0];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

        //NSLog(@"Download = %f", (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead);

    }];
    [operation start];
}

-(void)downloadRequestedImage : (NSString *)imageURL :(NSInteger) type :(NSString *)imgName{

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10000.0];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *posterOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];
    posterOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
    [posterOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

        UIImage *secImg = responseObject;
        if(type == 1) { // Delete the image from DB
            [self removeImage:imgName];
        }
        [self AddImageIntoDocument:secImg :imgName];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Image request failed with error: %@", error);
    }];

    [posterOperation start];
}
```

**The above code i am looping according to the number of videos and images that i have to download**

What is the reason behind that behaviour

I even have screen shots of memory allocation for both the scenarios

Please Help

Adding code for saving the downloaded images also

```
-(void)AddImageIntoDocument :(UIImage *)img :(NSString *)str{

    if(img) {
        NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.4);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *filePathName =[[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        [pngData writeToFile:filePathName atomically:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Network Error while downloading the image!!! Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that you're loading your large files into memory (and presumably it's happening quickly enough that you app isn't having a chance to respond to memory pressure notifications).

You can mitigate this by controlling the peak memory usage by not loading these downloads into memory. When download large files, it's often better to stream them directly to persistent storage. To do this with AFNetworking, you can set the `outputStream` of the `AFURLConnectionOperation`, and it should stream the contents directly to that file, e.g.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path          = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]]; // use whatever path is appropriate for your app

operation.outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"successful");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure: %@", error);
}];

[self.downloadQueue addOperation:operation];
```

---

BTW, you'll notice that I'm not just calling `start` on these requests. Personally, I always add them to a queue for which I've specified the maximum number of concurrent operations:

```
self.downloadQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
self.downloadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
self.downloadQueue.name = @"com.domain.app.downloadQueue";
```

I think this is less critical regarding memory usage than the streaming of the results directly to a `outputStream` using persistent storage, but I find this is another mechanism for managing system resources when initiating many concurrent requests.

Comment: what is the difference between outputStreamToFileAtPath and initToFileAtPath.. at the time of downloading and writing it to persistant stroe i didn't find any difference

Comment: You're 100% correct that there is no difference (at least a difference that's material here) regarding those two techniques. But you use the output stream approach in `AddVideoIntoDocument` (but, as an aside, you don't appear to do anything with it when its done), but in `downloadRequestedImage`, you're loading the images into memory rather than streaming them to persistent storage. I confess that I didn't notice that the former was using output stream at all, but was fixating on the fact that the latter was not streaming.

Comment: @kumar As an aside, you didn't share `AddImageIntoDocument`, so it's unclear what the memory implications of that method are. (Is that method keeping stuff in some memory structure?) Make sure you're not trying to hold all of the images in memory at one time.

Comment: @kumar OK, so what you're doing is downloading the `NSData` of the image, converting it to a `UIImage`, converting it back to another `NSData` (which will be different than original one) and saving that. So, for every image download in progress, you're holding the image in memory three times. You should just use the same output stream technique that you used in `AddVideoIntoDocument`, and (a) it will be far more efficient use of memory; and (b) you won't suffer any image degradation that your current code experiences.

Comment: if i use nsoutputstream, how can i assure that the image is downloaded properly?

Comment: I'd try using `AFImageResponseSerializer` in conjunction with output stream (I confess I've never used that combination, but you should try it out). If worse comes to worse, use `outputStream` and try creating `UIImage` when done and make sure it succeeds. That's not ideal (as you're loading the whole image in memory at one time), but at least we're only talking about one copy of the image being held in memory at one time.

Comment: I tried using NSURLSessionDownloadTask and it seems like consuming less memory while downloading and saving the images, so i changed the implementation to NSURLSession

Answer (score 0):

You can start using `NSURLSession`'s downloadTask.

I think this will resolve your issue.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someSite.com/somefile.zip"]];
[[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
     {
         // Use location (it's file URL in your system)
     }];
```